# Check out a read-only copy of a file from Subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control

Sometimes I want to get a file from a repository for use in some project that's not under source control. Let's say it's just a file full of handy utility functions. I know I can just to an **svn export** but I'd like to be able to do an **svn update** from time to time to get the latest version of the file.

The important thing is I don't want to be able to commit any changes to the file from the new project; I just want to be able to do updates to refresh the file.

Is there any way to checkout a file as read-only?

Comment: why not simply do another export?

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, thanks. Export commands are a bit cumbersome; you've got to include the long repository URL, your username, and your password. It's nice to checkout because you get the .svn file that remembers all that stuff. Still, good answer.

Comment: You don't say which platform you are on, but with Tortoise SVN export is pretty much  a single-click operation.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like emulating the [CVS read-only checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146655/cvs-read-only-check-out), and I do not think it has been [implemented in Subversion](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2004-11/0823.shtml).

The ideal scenario would be to remove commit access on the server side, but I suppose your user need to modify a file in a certain workspace, while *not* modifying (and comiting) the same file in another environment (i.e. in that project which is not under source control).

Another possibility would be to merge that file into a **SVN branch declared as read-only** (through a [per-directory access setting](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir)).
That way, you can update the file in this branch , but your users who checkout that file won't be able to commit that file, while retaining the possibility to commit on the repository.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is, when you check out the file, add a property to it (locally!) like `readonly` or some such.  You can even script up a read-only-checkout sequence that does it for you in one step.  This, in itself, does not make the file read-only.

What you can do is, write a pre-commit hook which does an `svnlook propget` into the potential transaction, and if `readonly` is defined, disallow the commit.

When you do a regular `svn update` it should work fine with no extra work.

This may be overkill, but if it's a feature you'd like to use often, it may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some form of build automation (make, ant, etc.) for compiling.  Why not add an 'update' step to your make file, that looks something like this:

```
update:
        svn update
        svn export <<export parameters go here>>
```

Then whenever someone would type `svn update` they can type `make update` and have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a subversion user who only has read access to the repository, then use that user to perform the checkout/updates.

Comment: Note that the Berkeley database backend [requires write access](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.basics.backends). See the _Usable from a read-only mount_ entry in the table.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, set the read-only bit.  In Eclipse, right-click on the file and check "Read Only".

[image: Read-Only]

Answer (score 0):

How do you like an idea to set a read-only attributes to checked out files? I wander if it is possible to automate this action in some kind of post-checkout handler/hook?

This will not prevent you from committing the changes though.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you want to ensure that you can't commit any changes that you make, so the files you checkout need to be read/write-able but you don't want to allow changes files to be checked in and occasionally you want to be able to `svn up` those files too.

For me, the solution was to make `.svn` un-writeable

Running linux/mac you can run `chmod -R -w .svn`. If you try to check anything in, you will get a readonly error. You can still diff, blame, and etc. The downside is that this will prevent you from `svn up`-ing until you make the directory readable again. However, you can just toggle writing on/off when you need to do that (`chmod -R +w .svn`).

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what the Windows equivalent would be.